# How can I display images from an arbitrary folder in Xamarin Forms on Windows 8

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.windows

This may be a dead horse, but I need to be able to supply a local folder full of images OUTSIDE my Xamarin application - not as resources, not requiring compilation to add more images - and display those images in the application, in Image objects. My main target platform is Windows 10. Others nice to have, not required.

Xamarin Forms Image normally takes either a File name (no path) or a URI. I can't get either method to locate and display images from the local file system. I must be doing something basic wrong.

Non-working sample:

```
Image i = new Image();
i.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(some.png); // Needs to be from folder on local disk
grid.Children.Add(i, c, r);
```

Most articles I find explain how to bundle images WITH the application as part of the source; again I need to display them in the application from a folder WITHOUT bundling them with the application. Users should be able to add more images to the folder and they would work in the app without recompiling/reinstalling - like an image gallery.

EDIT: I am able to successfully read a text file using PCLStorage https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage. Is there a way to wire that to Xamarin forms image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to write a platform specific class to read the images and return a stream that could be consumed by StreamImageSource.  Then you can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to expose this behavior to your Forms PCL.

Alternatively, you could use [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage)

```
  var f = await FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.GetFileAsync (path);

  Stream s = await f.OpenAsync (FileAccess.Read);
  image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => s);
```

Comment: I am able to read a text file from disk using the PCLStorage (see note above). Can that work for images?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to return a stream that the StreamImageSource can use

Comment: Works! Thank you. I need to get my head around the whole asyc / await pattern (I'm only an amateur c# developer :-) but passing a stream works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. If you don't bundle the images with your application, you somehow have to transfer the images to the application. Most common case is that you serve these images on a web server somewhere, where the application downloads the images from that web server.